# Hyper-V Server Management from Windows 8.1

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-8.1

Is there a way to manage a Hyper-V cluster that runs on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter from a Windows 8.1 Pro workstation?

I've downloaded and installed the Remote Server Admin Tools for 8.1 (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39296), but when I enable the Hyper-V manager, it tells me that I can't manage Hyper-V servers on 2K8 or 2K8R2.

Related, the Failover Cluster Manager barfs with a similar error.

How do I manage my old servers with my new workstation?

Comment: Create a Win7 VM in Hyper-V on your Win 8.1 workstation. :)

Comment: It'll be VMware Player, but yeah, that sounds like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using a different OS would get rid of the compability issues between Windows 8 and 2k8 / 2k8R2. For optimal results you want to use the corresponding OS depending on your server.

Server 2003 : Win XP

2008 / 2008R2 : Win 7

2012 : Win 8

Unfortunately apart from running a VM using Win 7 or using a completely different machine, i dont think RSAT will work on your Win 8 machine. Hope this helps

Comment: Useful? No.  Reality?... yes.

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather old but might come in handy for someone later on.

I've succesfully used this 5nine product in the past, though i only needed to manage one single Hyper-V 2008 host, not a cluster. Looking at the feature list it does say cluster management is possible.

5nine Manager 5.2 for Hyper-V
http://www.5nine.com/5nine-manager-for-hyper-v-product.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can install the System Center Virtual Machine Manager and add your cluster resources to your Fabric. Then you have only to install the SCVMM console on your Workstation to manager your Cluster and your Cluster Resources, Hyper-V nodes etc.

Cheers,

ankso